# Highcharts: some columns are missing when a bar chart changes to a column chart

Tags: highcharts

I am developing a website and using Highcharts. I have a bar/column chart selection. The chart is first displayed in bar chart, and then using the following code switch between the two chart types:

Code for changing to bar chart:

```
var chart = code for find the chart object
chart.inverted = true;
chart.xAxis[0].update({}, false);
chart.yAxis[0].update({}, false);
chart.series[0].update({
    type: 'bar'
});
```

The following code is for changing to column chart:

```
var chart = code for find the chart object
chart.inverted = false;
chart.xAxis[0].update({}, true);
chart.yAxis[0].update({}, true);
chart.series[0].update({
    type: 'column'
});
```

When the chart is first displayed in bar chart, all the data are displayed. However, when changed to column chart, some columns are missing. Please see the below picture. If I change it to bar chart, all the data are still there.

[image]

What could the cause for this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found code here works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/lorwynz_11/sSLnn/3/

for column chart

```
    options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
    options.chart.type = 'column';
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

for bar chart

```
    options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
    options.chart.type = 'bar';
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Cheers!